# Spring MVC Handling Tabs as Separate Forms

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I would like some advice on the following scenario: I have a form that is divided into tabs each tab represents its own **Model Attribute** I would like to display all the tabs with their fields when the user request the page.

However I would like each of them to have their own Controller so when a POST is made each is handled separately. When a request for the page is made I use one controller to get the page and prepare the list boxes and populate them and displays it to the user. Not all the fields are being displayed for the **'Punishment'** tab I am only able to see the Punishment Number label on the Punishment Tab. Under is my code:

**Citizens_Registration.html**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


    <head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



        <style>
            <%@ include file="../css/forms.css" %>


        </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#skinColorId').change(function(){


            var skinId = $('select#skinColorId').val();


            $('#skinColorPreviewer').css({backgroundColor: skinId});
        });


        $('#eyeColorId').change(function(){


            var eyeId = $('select#eyeColorId').val();


            $('#eyeColorPreviewer').css({backgroundColor: eyeId});
        });


        $('#hairColorId').change(function(){


            var hairId = $('select#hairColorId').val();


            $('#hairColorPreviewer').css({backgroundColor: hairId});
        });

        //$("#divLeft").height($("#divRight").height());

    });

     $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });

    </script>

    <title>Citizen Registration</title>

    </head>

    <body>  
        <div id="tabs"> 

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1">Citizen Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Punishment</a></li>

        </ul>



<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------CHARACTERISTICS INFO------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <div id="tab1">
            <form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="post" modelAttribute="citizens" action="citizen_registration.htm">

                    <fieldset>  
                    <legend>Characteristics Info</legend>
                            <ol>    
                                <li><form:label for="photo" path="photo">Select Photo</form:label>
                                    <form:input path="photo" type="file" id="photo" title="Upload a photo"/><form:errors path="photo" id="errors"/></li>

                                <li>
                                    <label>Select Gender</label>
                                    <form:select path="genderId" id="genderId" title="Select Your Gender">
                                    <form:options items = "${gender.genderList}" itemValue="genderId" itemLabel="genderDesc" />
                                    </form:select>
                                    <form:errors path="genderId" class="errors"/>
                                </li>               

                                <li><form:label for="weight" path="weight">Enter Weight <i>(lbs)</i></form:label>
                                    <form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight"/><form:errors path="weight" id="errors"/>
                                </li> 

                                <li><form:label for="height" path="height">Enter Height <i>(feet)</i></form:label>
                                    <form:input path="height" id="height" title="Enter Height"/><form:errors path="height" id="errors"/>
                                </li> 

                                <li>
                                    <form:label for="skinColorId" path="skinColorId">Select Skin Color</form:label>     
                                    <form:select path="skinColorId" id="skinColorId" title="Select Skin Color">
                                    <form:options items = "${skinColor.skinColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc" style="background-color: ${color}" />
                                    </form:select>          
                                    <form:errors path="skinColorId" id="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="skinColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <form:label for="eyeColorId" path="eyeColorId">Select Eye Color</form:label>        
                                    <form:select path="eyeColorId" id="eyeColorId">
                                    <form:options items = "${eyeColor.eyeColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc"/>
                                    </form:select>          
                                    <form:errors path="eyeColorId" id="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="eyeColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
                                </li>               

                                <li>
                                    <form:label for="hairColorId" path="hairColorId">Select Hair Color</form:label>     
                                    <form:select path="hairColorId" id="hairColorId" title="Select Hair Color">
                                    <form:options items = "${hairColor.hairColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc" />
                                    </form:select>          
                                    <form:errors path="hairColorId" id="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="hairColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
                                </li>

                                <li><form:label for="noticeableFeatures" path="noticeableFeatures">Noticeable Features</form:label>
                                    <form:textarea path="noticeableFeatures" id="noticeableFeatures" title="State Noticable Features e.g. scars, marks, moles....."/><form:errors path="noticeableFeatures" id="errors"/>
                                </li> 
                            </ol>
                            </fieldset>



                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Professional & Other Information</legend>
                        <ol>        
                            <li>
                                <form:label for ="ethnicityId" path="ethnicityId">Select Ethnicity</form:label>     
                                <form:select path="ethnicityId" id="ethnicityId" title="Select Ethnicity">
                                <form:options items = "${ethnicity.ethnicityList}" itemValue="ethnicityId" itemLabel="ethnicityDesc" />
                                </form:select>          
                                <form:errors path="ethnicityId" id="errors"/>
                            </li>           

                            <li>
                                <form:label for="occupationId" path="occupationId">Select Occupation</form:label>       
                                <form:select path="occupationId" id="occupationId" title="Select Occupation">
                                <form:options items = "${occupation.occupationList}" itemValue="occupationId" itemLabel="occupationDesc" />
                                </form:select>  
                                <form:errors path="occupationId" id="errors"/>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <form:label for="maritalStatusId" path="maritalStatusId">Select Marital Status</form:label>     
                                <form:select path="maritalStatusId" id="maritalStatusId" title="Select Marital Status">
                                <form:options items = "${maritalStatus.maritalStatusList}" itemValue="maritalStatusId" itemLabel="maritalStatusDesc" />
                                </form:select>  
                                <form:errors path="maritalStatusId" id="errors"/>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                        </fieldset>


                <fieldset>
                <legend>Identity Information</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>Social Security No</label>
                                    <form:input path="socialSecurityNumber"/><form:errors path="socialSecurityNumber" id="errors"/><label id="socialSecurityNumber"></label>
                            </li>                   

                            <li>
                                <form:label for="citizenTypeId" path="CitizenTypeId">Select Citizen Type</form:label>
                                <form:select path="citizenTypeId" id="citizenTypeId" title="Select Citizen Type">
                                <form:options items = "${citizenType.citizenTypeList}" itemValue="citizenTypeId" itemLabel="citizenTypeDesc" />
                                </form:select>
                                <form:errors path="citizenTypeId" id="errors"/>
                            </li>


                            <li><label>First Name</label>
                                <form:input path="fName" id="fName" title="Enter First Name"/><form:errors path="fName" id="errors"/><label id="fName"></label></li>

                            <li><label>Last Name</label>
                                <form:input path="lName" id="lName" title="Enter Last Name"/><form:errors path="lName" id="errors"/></li>

                            <li><label>Other Name / Nick Name</label>
                                <form:input path="oName" id="oName" title="Enter Other Name"/><form:errors path="oName" id="errors"/></li>

                            <li><label>Date Of Birth</label>
                                <form:input path="dob" id="dob" title="Date Of Birth"/><form:errors path="dob" id="errors"/></li> 
                        </ol>
                        </fieldset>



                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
                        <ol>                                            
                            <li>
                                <form:label for="countryId" path="countryId">Select Country</form:label>
                                <form:select path="countryId" id="countryId" title="Select Country">
                                <form:options items = "${country.countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName" />
                                </form:select>
                                <form:errors path="countryId" id="errors"/>
                            </li>   

                            <li><form:label for="addLn1" path="addLn1">Address Line 1</form:label>
                                <form:input path="addLn1" id="addLn1" title="Enter Address Line 1"/><form:errors path="addLn1" id="errors"/>
                            </li>

                            <li><form:label for ="addLn2" path="addLn2">Address Line 2</form:label>
                                <form:input path="addLn2" id="addLn2" title="Enter Address Line 2"/><form:errors path="addLn2" id="errors"/>
                            </li>

                            <li><form:label for ="addLn3" path="addLn3">Address Line 3</form:label>
                                <form:input path="addLn3" id="addLn3" title="Enter Address Line 3"/><form:errors path="addLn3" id="errors"/>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <form:label for="phoneNo" path="phoneNo">Phone Number</form:label>
                                <form:input path="phoneNo" id="phoneNo" title="Enter Phone Number"/><form:errors path="phoneNo" id="errors"/>
                            </li>




                            </br>
                            <li><input type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Save" />
                                <input type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Update" />
                            </li>       

                        </ol>
                            <label id="results">${results}</label>
                            <label id="Error">${error}</label>
                        </fieldset>

                </form:form>
             </div> 

<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------TAB 2--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->


            <div id="tab2">
                <form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="post" modelAttribute="punishment" action="punishment_registration.htm">

                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <form:label for ="punishmentId" path="punishmentId">Punishment Number</form:label>
                        <form:input path="punishmentId" id="punishmentId"/><form:errors path="punishmentId" id="errors"/>                   
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <form:label for="crimeRecNo" path="crimeRecNo">Select Crime</form:label>
                        <form:select path="crimeRecNo" id="CrimeRecNo" title="Select Crime">
                        <form:options items = "${crime.crimeList}" itemValue="crimeRecNo" itemLabel="crimeRecNo"/>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:errors path="crimeRecNo" id="errors"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <form:label for="punishmentTypeId" path="punishmentTypeId">Select Crime</form:label>
                        <form:select path="punishmentTypeId" id="punishmentTypeId" title="Select Punishment Type">
                        <form:options items = "${punishmentType.punishmentTypeList}" itemValue="punishmentTypeId" itemLabel="punishmentTypeDesc"/>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:errors path="punishmentTypeId" id="errors"/>
                    </li>       

                    <li>
                        <form:label for ="monitoringStDate" path="monitoringStDate"> Start Date </form:label>
                        <form:input path="monitoringStDate" id="monitoringStDate"/><form:errors path="monitoringStDate" id="errors"/>                   
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <form:label for ="monitoringEnDate" path="monitoringEnDate"> End Date </form:label>
                        <form:input path="monitoringEnDate" id="monitoringEnDate"/><form:errors path="monitoringEnDate" id="errors"/>                   
                    </li>                   
                </ol>               

                </form:form>            
            </div>                      


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CitizenRegistrationController.java**

imports.......

```
@Controller
public class CitizenRegistrationController {


    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


    @Autowired
    private CitizenTypeManager citizenTypeManager;
    @Autowired
    private ColorManager colorManager;
    @Autowired
    private CountryManager countryManager;
    @Autowired  
    private EthnicityManager ethnicityManager;
    @Autowired
    private GenderManager genderManager;
    @Autowired
    private MaritalStatusManager maritalStatusManager;
    @Autowired
    private OccupationManager occupationManager;
    @Autowired
    private CrimeManager crimeManager;
    @Autowired
    private PunishmentTypeManager punishmentTypeManager;



    Map<String, Object> myCitizenType    = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myGender         = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myMaritalStatus  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myOccupation     = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myHairColor      = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> mySkinColor      = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myEyeColor       = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myCountry        = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myEthnicity      = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myCrimes         = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myPunishmentType = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @InitBinder("citizens")

    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){


        //removes white spaces 
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));

        //formats date 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //By passing true this will convert empty strings to null
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);


        //binder.setValidator(new OfficerRegistrationValidation());
        //binder.setValidator(officerRegistrationValidation);


    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value="citizen_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadPage(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                 @ModelAttribute Citizens citizen, Punishment punishment,
                                 BindingResult result,
                                 ModelMap m, Model model) throws Exception {

        try{
             logger.debug("In Http method for CitizenRegistrationController");


             myCitizenType.put("citizenTypeList",       this.citizenTypeManager.getCitizenType());
             myGender.put("genderList",                 this.genderManager.getGenderList());             
             myMaritalStatus.put("maritalStatusList",   this.maritalStatusManager.getMaritalStatus());
             myOccupation.put("occupationList",         this.occupationManager.getOccupations());
             myHairColor.put("hairColorList",           this.colorManager.getHairColors());
             mySkinColor.put("skinColorList",           this.colorManager.getSkinColors());
             myEyeColor.put("eyeColorList",             this.colorManager.getEyeColors());
             myCountry.put("countryList",               this.countryManager.getCountries());
             myEthnicity.put("ethnicityList",           this.ethnicityManager.getEthnicity());
             myCrimes.put("crimeList",                  this.crimeManager.getCrimes());
             myPunishmentType.put("punishmentTypeList", this.punishmentTypeManager.getPunishmentType());

             model.addAttribute("gender",        myGender);
             model.addAttribute("citizenType",   myCitizenType);
             model.addAttribute("maritalStatus", myMaritalStatus);
             model.addAttribute("occupation",    myOccupation);
             model.addAttribute("hairColor",     myHairColor);
             model.addAttribute("skinColor",     mySkinColor);
             model.addAttribute("eyeColor",      myEyeColor);
             model.addAttribute("country",       myCountry);
             model.addAttribute("ethnicity",     myEthnicity);
             model.addAttribute("crime",         myCrimes);
             model.addAttribute("punishmentType",myPunishmentType);




            return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
            request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
            return new ModelAndView("error_page");  


        }   

    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value="punishment_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loadPage(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                 @ModelAttribute Punishment punishment,
                                 BindingResult result,
                                 ModelMap m, Model model) throws Exception {

        try{
             logger.debug("In Http method for CitizenRegistrationController - Punishment Registration");


            //TODO




            return new ModelAndView("punishment_registration");

        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - - Punishment Registration : ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
            request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
            return new ModelAndView("error_page");  


        }   

    }

    /**
     * @param citizenTypeManager the citizenTypeManager to set
     */
    public void setCitizenTypeManager(CitizenTypeManager citizenTypeManager) {
        this.citizenTypeManager = citizenTypeManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param colorManager the colorManager to set
     */
    public void setColorManager(ColorManager colorManager) {
        this.colorManager = colorManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param countryManager the countryManager to set
     */
    public void setCountryManager(CountryManager countryManager) {
        this.countryManager = countryManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param ethnicityManager the ethnicityManager to set
     */
    public void setEthnicityManager(EthnicityManager ethnicityManager) {
        this.ethnicityManager = ethnicityManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param genderManager the genderManager to set
     */
    public void setGenderManager(GenderManager genderManager) {
        this.genderManager = genderManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param maritalStatusManager the maritalStatusManager to set
     */
    public void setMaritalStatusManager(MaritalStatusManager maritalStatusManager) {
        this.maritalStatusManager = maritalStatusManager;
    }
    /**
     * @param occupationManager the occupationManager to set
     */
    public void setOccupationManager(OccupationManager occupationManager) {
        this.occupationManager = occupationManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param myCrimes the myCrimes to set
     */
    public void setMyCrimes(Map<String, Object> myCrimes) {
        this.myCrimes = myCrimes;
    }


    /**
     * @param punishmentTypeManager the punishmentTypeManager to set
     */
    public void setPunishmentTypeManager(PunishmentTypeManager punishmentTypeManager) {
        this.punishmentTypeManager = punishmentTypeManager;
    }



}
```

Comment: I couldn't grok your entre question - you need more explanation and less code. It sounds like you are making it way more complex than it needs to be - you didn't convince me of the need to have each tab be a separate controller. Also, looking at your controller code it seems to me that all those `HashMap`s you are creating and then putting in the `model` are redundant - you are only populating a single element with (virtually) the same key name as the attribute name itself. Why not simply add the list to the model directly, like `model.addAttribute("crime", this.crimeManager.getCrimes());`?

Comment: i figured out the error one of my list items was returning NULL however i do embrace your comment and will look at my code

Comment: I intend to make calls to these HashMaps at different locations in the controller and using the myGender etc. is easier to call rather than thi.genderManager.getgenderList() every time. The code isn't yet completed maybe that why it would see like redundant code at this point